# How do I plot just a single column of a dataframe in Pandas against the datetime index using matplotlib

Tags: pandas

I have tried using plt.plot to plot a column of my dataframe against the index, but the x-axis is jumbled together. I thought there might be an easier way to do it in pandas, but not sure how to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
from datetime import datetime
import math
from scipy import signal

% matplotlib qt
file_17c= "C.txt"

df_17c = pd.read_csv(file_17c,sep ='\t', header = None,names = ['TimeStamp','x','y','z'],  usecols =[0,3,4,5])


df_17c = df_17c.iloc[13:,:].reset_index(drop = True) # start the DF at 00:00:00 to 23:59:59

date = '2019-03-17T'  # T is for isoformat
df_17c['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_17c['TimeStamp'].apply(lambda s: date+s))# add the date to the time and make datetime pbject
df_17c.set_index(df_17c['TimeStamp'],drop = True, inplace = True)
del df_17c['TimeStamp']

df_17c['x_mAvg'] = df_17c['x'].rolling(30).mean() - df_17c['x']
df_17c['x_mAvg'] = df_17c['x_mAvg'].fillna(method = 'backfill')

print(df_17c['x_mAvg']_

              x       y     z   x_mAvg
TimeStamp               
2019-03-17  26793   -216    0   2.3
2019-03-17  26792   -215    0   2.3
2019-03-17  26790   -215    0   2.3
2019-03-17  26793   -215    0   2.3
2019-03-17  26792   -214    0   2.3
```

I was hoping to get a nice x-axis that is the same as when you plot all columns of the dataframe using df.plot()

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you provide sample data? otherwise it's harder to tell what's wrong with your code since there's no output

Comment: We don't have `C.txt` so we can't really test against your data. What plotting code have you tried so far? What is the result of `df_17c.plot(y='x_mAvg')`?

Comment: I am not very efficient a programming or else I would try to create some dummy data. I could not find the image of the plot that was created to add to the question to give context. I am working on it.